# Part of my (GitLab) Pelican site is a pelican theme. What's gittiest way to install that theme within my project?

Tags: git, gitlab, pelican

I am building a pelican site hosted by gitlab. I want that site to use a pelican theme. (The site in progress can currently be seen at http://jerrya.gitlab.io/heuristk)

Many pelican themes seem to be a subdirectory of a huge pelican git repo https://github.com/getpelican/pelican-themes. In this case I want to use the zurb-F5-basic theme. https://github.com/getpelican/pelican-themes/tree/master/zurb-F5-basic but I don't want to install EVERY pelican theme.

I'd like to install it in my repo as something like:

heuristic/content/theme/zurb-F5-basic

and have git commands done in heuristic/content/theme/zurb-F5-basic refer to the pelican theme repository

while git commands done in heuristic/content/ and heuristic refer to my gitlab site repository.

How do I install a pelican theme within my pelican site so that:

1. I can maintain a git remote repository at gitlab for my site
2. I can update the pelican theme from the pelican theme git repo.
3. And I want to install just zurb, not every pelican theme

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to achieve is not possible. At least not in exact that way.

Git has two features which allow you to somehow truncate a repository.

First, you can do `shallow` clones which are limited in the size of the repository history.

Second, there are so called `sparse checkouts`. A sparse checkout is basically a restricted representation of the repositories contents in your working directory. As I understand, with this, you basically select which parts of the repository should be presented to you in your working directory.
However, the whole repository is still held in the background.

I think `sparse checkouts` are the way to go, if you want to achieve something which comes close to your desired structure. The only difference is that you would have one folder in between:

> heuristic/content/theme/pt/zurb-F5-basic

Here, `pt` **is** the pelican themes repository as a submodule to your GitLab repository, but configured in a way that it only provides one sub-folder, namely "zurb-F5-basic".

```
# create the submodule
$ git submodule add https://github.com/getpelican/pelican-themes heuristic/content/theme/pt
$ cd heuristic/content/theme/pt
# activate sparse checkouts
$ git config core.sparsecheckout true
# define which file(s) should be shown in the working directory
$ echo "zurb-F5-basic" >> ../../../../.git/modules/heuristic/content/theme/pt/info/sparse-checkout
# apply the "filter"
$ git read-tree -mu HEAD
$ ls
zurb-F5-basic
```

Overall:

1. Yes
2. Yes
3. Depends on your definition of install, I would say: No

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. My issue with checking out the entire history or the entire project is wasting gitlab's disk space.

I'm not sure why I need the history of files I haven't checked out... but okay.

Comment: You can avoid checking out the entire history of a project using **shallow** clones. By specifying the depth _n_, e.g. ``--depth 1`` when checking out a project you limit the local clone to the last _n_ commits. This means that you actually save disk space.
Reality check: I just tested it myself, 59MB vs 54MB when only checking out the last commit of the pelican themes repository. I suppose git does a good job when compressing those roughly 800 commits.
But still, with shallow copies you can save space!

Comment: I would like to add that the themes repository does have many many submodules. Your theme is an exception to that. If you would choose another theme which is actually provided by a submodule you could of course simply add the corresponding repository to your pelican and you're fine.

Comment: Did this answer your question?